# I want to make sure if ng-click="aFunction" is clicked twice than it should do this "!aFunction", is this possible without writing a Loc

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

```
<div ng-click="selectPhoto(pic); !selectPhoto(pic)">
      <span ng-repeat="p in photos"><img></span>
</div>
```

Is this possible without extra LOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unforunately, No you can't.

I think that you have to create new $scope and on every click change the value..

In case if you are working on single photo:

```
<div ng-click="doSomething(pic)">
  <span ng-repeat="p in photos"><img></span>
</div>
 $scope.isClicked = 0;
  $scope.doSomething =function(pic){
   $scope.isClicked +=1;
   if($scope.isClicked %2 ==0){
      selectPhoto(pic);
 }else{
      !selectPhoto(pic);
 }
}
```

In case if you many photos, same like above except the counter.

```
$scope.pic.counter=0;
```

Whic mean that every pic must include counter prop.

I hope that helps

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I first thought of doing, but now working with one photo at a time (easy way). This can be useful while working with multiple photos